# In likelihood ratio formula, what does the exponent mean?

Tags: probability, machine-learning, maximum-likelihood, log-likelihood

In **section 3.2.1** of Kevin Murphy's Machine Learning textbook, the likelihood of the dataset is denoted by the following:

$p(D|h) = [{1 \over size(h)}]^N = [{1 \over |h|}]^N$

What does the *N* term represent and why?

**Also**, in the event that it is the probability of choosing N terms from the **concept extension h** (which is a subset of our range of numbers from which we are allowed to pick from), then why is it 1/size(h) and not size(h)/size([entire range of numbers])? It seems the latter would make more sense as far as probability goes.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The author means by $p(D|h) = [{1 \over size(h)}]^N = [{1 \over |h|}]^N$ - the probability of independently chosen $N$ neccessary items  with replacements from $h$ - which is our sample space, not $N$, $N$ - is a number of trying in our experiment.

Let $D= \{3\}$ is our example chosen from $h=\{3,6,9,12\}$. then $p(D|h)=\tfrac{1}{4}$ - the prob. to chose $\{3\}$ from $|h|=4$ elements. By independency condition after $N$ such trials with replacements: $p(D|h\bigcap D|h\bigcap D|h\bigcap...\bigcap D|h)=p(D|h)\bigcap...p(D|h)=[\tfrac {1}{4}]^N$.

Comment: Ok, so then if it is not possible to choose one of the numbers twice, why is the probability "with replacement"? Thanks in advance

Comment: "with replacements" was taken from original condition from Murphy's book, you find the probability that your specific example $D=\{i\}$ appears $N$ times, when $N=2$, you must multiply your prob. $2$ times and so on... it's follow from independent and replacements condition, see detail here: http://www.probabilityformula.org/probability-with-replacement.html#

Comment: sorry I said the question wrong .... what I really meant was, for example, if **D = {_3, 9_}** and **h = {_3, 6, 9, 12_}**, and we were fortunate enough to select _3_ on the first selection, why would we replace _3_? Its clearly not possible to select the same one twice, so why wouldn't it be _without_ replacement? Thank you

Comment: ''with replacement'' means after every trial we return our chosen element to $h$ http://www.statisticshowto.com/sampling-with-replacement-without/

Comment: I know what replacement means, but **why** are we replacing them in this case? Once we select, say, 3, we will not select that one again, right or wrong? Thank you